# How to use `pgfornamentline` with han symbols?

Tags: pgfornament

The `pgfornament` package provides a `pgfornamentline` macro.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfornament-han}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=12cm,y=12cm]
        \node (TL) at (0, 1) {};
        \node (TR) at (1, 1) {};
        \pgfornamentline{TL}{TR}6{88}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to use han symbols (e.g. `\pgfornamenthan{33}`) in the last argument? `pgfornamentlinehan` nor `pgfornamenthanline` does exist.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf), you can switch between symbol families with

```
\begin{newfamily}[<family>]
stuff
\end{newfamily}
```

`vectorian` is the default, so you need to switch to `pgfhan`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{newfamily}[pgfhan]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=12cm,y=12cm]
        \node (TL) at (0, 1) {};
        \node (TR) at (1, 1) {};
        \pgfornamentline[color=red]{TL}{TR}{6}{45}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{newfamily}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will put a brown-color :-)...very good answer.